# resourses.ap_ missing does not exist?

Tags: android, exception, filenotfoundexception

During the last 4 hours,I am getting crazy about an error that appears in my console screen,which comes from the compiling of a simple HelloWorld app. Everything was working fine,and now this:(

```
Description Path    Resource    Location    Type

Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Theodosios 
\workspace\HelloApp\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist        HelloApp    Unknown Android 
Packaging Problem
```

I updated the SDK,did the clean things many times,and still I am stuck. I also looked around the net about this problem,but none of the solutions I saw worked.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is the simple code.

```
package com.example.helloapp;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The console output when eclipse is opened gives me lots of errors.

```
[2015-01-04 23:35:48 - HelloApp] C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\Programs\Concept  
Maniax\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat 
\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No 
 resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

 [2015-01-04 23:35:48 - HelloApp] 
 [2015-01-04 23:35:48 - HelloApp] C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\Programs\Concept M

 Maniax\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat 

 \res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No   
 resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
 
 [2015-01-04 23:35:48 - HelloApp] 
 [2015-01-04 23:35:48 - HelloApp] C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\Programs\Concept 
 Maniax\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
 \res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No 
 resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.

 [2015-01-04 23:35:48 - HelloApp] 

 [2015-01-04 23:35:48 - HelloApp] C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\Programs\Concept 
 Maniax\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
  \res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No 
 resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
```

and so on. Maybe there is something wrong with android-21 api,that causes the missing resource.ap_ exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

Create an dummy file in the mentioned path and then clean - build the project.

or

Delete the Bin folder and then do project clean-build.

Comment: you mean any file in ending in txt? I will try it now!

Comment: @Theo, post your code sample of all files, java, xml and if any resources